# Display servlet errors in JSP using JSTL or EL

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, jstl

I want to display error messages e.g SQLException errors in the jsp page that the servlet has redirected to. I am new in java and JSP but I have managed to get basic things like saving data using a servlet to a database working. Below is my code for catching errors encountered

```
 catch(SQLException e){
         out.println("SQL Error encountered "+e.getMessage());
```

How can I catch this error into a jsp page that has been redirected to by the servlet using jstl or Expression Language? E.g if an admin submits a duplicate email address from a page called createuser.jsp, the error should be displayed in creatuser.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never post exception related material to your front end since this can provide information on your internal structure and underlying architecture which is never a good idea since it could lead to possible attacks.

What you could do would be to do some sort of form validation, as shown in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983622/form-filling-validation-in-java) and, as in your case, instead of showing exception messages, you simply make a check for the name and if it throws and exception, just display a message on the screen something like so: `User Already Exists!`. Error messages such as these are usually also less confusing for non technical people.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the message as an attribute of your request:

Servlet:

```
catch(SQLException e) {
    request.setAttribute("exception", "SQL error encountered");
}
```

Jsp:

```
${exception}
```

Comment: Actually your solution worked when I included the requestdipatcher and when I redirected to the jsp. However all my page styling have disappeared and the new url reads http://path/to/page/saveuser.do saveuser.do is my servlet mapping name i used in web.xml Clicking on any link from here just shows a not found error. Can I use sendRedirect?